# Save panda boxplot as image

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I'm trying to save a `pandas.DataFrame.boxplot` variable to a image to use it with a Qt widget, but I don't know how to convert this variable. I have this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np


df = DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5))
plt.figure();
bp = df.boxplot()
```

And Spyder shows it:
[image]

Are there instructions to do it automatically within the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for a standard image format?

If so this will do the trick:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.savefig()
```

docs:
https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have multiple figures and you want to save them independently when you want in the code: make sure you can access it by a unique name:

```
fig100 = figure()        
outputBoxplot100 = df_100.boxplot(column=['1', '2', '4', '5', '8'])
plt.title("100 MHz")
fig150 = figure()
outputBoxplot150 = df_150.boxplot(column=['1', '2', '4', '5', '8'])
plt.title("150 MHz")

# do other stuff

fig100.savefig("test100.svg", format="svg")
fig150.savefig("test150.svg", format="svg")
```

In this case, I would change your code in:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np


df = DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5))
myFig = plt.figure();
bp = df.boxplot()
myFig.savefig("myName.svg", format="svg")
```

The result will be a saved file named "myName.svg":

[image]

**Please note:** I am using `svg` but you can use the format you like the most ( `png`, `jpeg`, etc) that this micro supports. Check on the availability on Pandas website.

Comment: I am getting an empty figure with this. It shows on Jupiter Notebook, but the saved .png file is a blank figure. Any thoughts?
Edit: if I copy and paste your code it works, but when doing my own dataset it saves an empty figure even thought it shows me the boxplots just as I expected! I tried .svg as well

Comment: @Jonathan, copy and paste a minimal amount of code to reproduce your error and ask a completely new question :) Remember: a few lines of code to reproduce your error. It is possible that, during this little homework effort, you can find the solution yourself :)